# Can I increase resistance to cut down on LED power consumption?

Tags: led, resistors

I am totally new to electronics, and it's just a small hobby. I have 10 LED's that I want to connect in series. I am hooking it up to 4x 1.5V batteries (it's what I had around), so I assume that becomes 6V.

Before I get to the LED's, I have a single 220 ohm resistor.

From what I understand, these 10 LED's should use up more than 6V, and not be able to glow.

Is it because of the resistor that they work? If I increase the resistor value, will it glow less, but last longer?

The only reason I put this resistor on, was to make sure nothing blew.

Comment: What is the forward voltage of these LEDs? Or a part number or datasheet link? If you don't have that info, what color LEDs are these?

Comment: 6V across a 220 ohm resistor gives a short-circuit current of 27 mA, which should be safe for any LED. What happened when you tried various comibnations of LEDs with your resistor and battery?

Comment: @AnindoGhosh They are all green, so I believe that is around 2? I'm affraid I don't have a part number or datasheet.

Comment: @DaveTweed, I didn't really try too much. I have a ton of resistors, so I can, but I was hoping to get some clarification first. The resistor I put on already, was really just to be sure, I didn't blow any of the LEDs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [LED Series Resistance Calculator](http://www.bowdenshobbycircuits.info/led.htm) to find out your series resistor.
I'm afraid that 6v cannot drive 10 LEDs in series. You would have to try a parallel approach or series+parallel combo approach to drive them.

If the forward voltage is not known guess around 2v to 2.4v and play with the calculator.

You are right, that if you increase resistor value, the LEDs will glow dimmer and your batteries will last longer. When you increase the resistor value, you are reducing the amount of current through the LEDs.

Comment: Have I misunderstood something then? They all do light up.

Comment: @Nicolai They light up because maybe your total (series) LED forward voltage is less than 6v. To determine that, add another LED of the same specification in series. Keep adding LED at a time until they don't light up. Then divide 6v by the number of LEDs in series. That will help you in calculating approximate forward voltage of each LED. This link may be helpful http://www.instructables.com/id/Determining-Forward-Voltages-of-LEDs/

Comment: Thanks Chetan, I do have a multimeter, so maybe I should try to measure something. The resistor doesn't have anything to do with them lighting?